# Index page Pagination remove single post on page 2

Tags: wordpress

The below code will display a single post (Recent post) on the home page or front page of my blog template and i want to remove the single post(Recent post) and replace it with some text say "older post " from page 2 onwards.

The problem the condition ***is_home()*** returns true when user clicks on page 2. since logically speaking it is a query request on home page . so  i tried replacing **is_home()** with **is_page(1)**  and also tired **is_front_page()**  but nothing gives fruit

[<del>Here</del>](http://www.cthreelabs.com/wp) <del>you can see the working code.</del>

```
<? if(is_home()) : ?>
  <div>
    <h3>Recent Post</h3>

    <? query_posts('posts_per_page=1');
     while(have_posts()):the_post();?>

    // iteration code here

     <!-- End Single Post -->
      <?php endwhile;wp_reset_query();?>

  </div> <!-- if condition ends-->

   <? else : ?>
   <div>
    <h3>Older Post</h3>
   </div>
  <? endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing 
    `(is_home())`
with 
    `(is_paged())` 
solved the problem.